# Hive queries in spark sql

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I can use any type of sql queries in spark.sql but while applying spark.sql in below queries its getting error. `(cstone_feed_key|cstone_last_updatetm|rte_call_key_seq_no)?+.+` sysntax mainly used to exclude the fields from the selection in hive. kindly suggest some way to do the same. I have around 1000 fields in the table.

select rte_call_key_seq_no as T_rte_call_key_seq_no, `(cstone_feed_key|cstone_last_updatetm|rte_call_key_seq_no)?+.+`
from table

Comment: do you need alternative for this? this is not supported, but not difficult to implement alternative if needed

Comment: please share the alternative way.

Comment: kindly share the alternative way.

Comment: added, please have a look

Answer (score 0):

**`update-1`**

```
spark.sql("SET spark.sql.parser.quotedRegexColumnNames=true")
    df.createOrReplaceTempView("table")
    spark.sql("select `(account_id|credit_card_limit)?+.+` from table")
      .printSchema()

    /**
      * root
      * |-- credit_card_Number: long (nullable = true)
      * |-- first_name: string (nullable = true)
      * |-- last_name: string (nullable = true)
      * |-- phone_number: integer (nullable = true)
      * |-- amount: integer (nullable = true)
      * |-- date: string (nullable = true)
      * |-- shop: string (nullable = true)
      * |-- transaction_code: string (nullable = true)
      */
```

**`original answer`**
alternative-

### hive syntax

1. The following query selects all columns except ds and hr.
2. Java regex syntax

```
SELECT `(ds|hr)?+.+` FROM sales
```

### Spark Syntax

**python**

```py
df = spark.createDataFrame([("a", 1), ("b", 2), ("c",  3)], ["Col1", "Col2"])
df.select(df.colRegex("`(Col1)?+.+`")).show()
+----+
|Col2|
+----+
|   1|
|   2|
|   3|
+----+
```

**scala**

```scala
df.select(df.colRegex("`(account_id|credit_card_limit)?+.+`"))
      .printSchema()

    /**
      * root
      * |-- credit_card_Number: long (nullable = true)
      * |-- first_name: string (nullable = true)
      * |-- last_name: string (nullable = true)
      * |-- phone_number: integer (nullable = true)
      * |-- amount: integer (nullable = true)
      * |-- date: string (nullable = true)
      * |-- shop: string (nullable = true)
      * |-- transaction_code: string (nullable = true)
      */
```

**Another Approach**

```scala
df.printSchema()

    /**
      * root
      * |-- account_id: integer (nullable = true)
      * |-- credit_card_Number: long (nullable = true)
      * |-- credit_card_limit: integer (nullable = true)
      * |-- first_name: string (nullable = true)
      * |-- last_name: string (nullable = true)
      * |-- phone_number: integer (nullable = true)
      * |-- amount: integer (nullable = true)
      * |-- date: string (nullable = true)
      * |-- shop: string (nullable = true)
      * |-- transaction_code: string (nullable = true)
      */

    // hive syntax
    // The following query selects all columns except ds and hr.
    // SELECT `(ds|hr)?+.+` FROM sales
    // Java regex syntax

    df.selectExpr(df.columns.filter(_.matches("(account_id|credit_card_limit)?+.+")): _*)
      .printSchema()

    /**
      * root
      * |-- credit_card_Number: long (nullable = true)
      * |-- first_name: string (nullable = true)
      * |-- last_name: string (nullable = true)
      * |-- phone_number: integer (nullable = true)
      * |-- amount: integer (nullable = true)
      * |-- date: string (nullable = true)
      * |-- shop: string (nullable = true)
      * |-- transaction_code: string (nullable = true)
      */
```

ref - [hive LanguageManual](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Select#LanguageManualSelect-REGEXColumnSpecification)

Comment: in case of spark.sql, should I use same logic?

Comment: i don't think, spark sql will parse it. go with spark DSL apis

Comment: you can create a variable using `df.columns.filter(_.matches("(account_id|credit_card_limit)?+.+")` and use the same variable within spark sql `select` expression

Comment: This is the error I am getting. cannot resolve '`(cstone_feed_key|cstone_last_updatetm|rte_call_key_seq_no)?+.+`

Comment: you can't use it directly in spark sql

Comment: I have shared my query in another post."Regex syntax in spark sql" please help me to convert.

Comment: Can you use pyspatk dataframe apis? If yes then it will be easy to convert the sql query you provided into pyspark df api.

Comment: @TuluSahoo, there is a way to use quotedRegex columns in spark sql. please check `update-1`